# Why can't I click my markers to pull up infowindow in Google Maps anymore?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a web application using the Google Maps API and has been working fine.  The page still works but one day randomly I found out that the markers can no longer be clicked but has worked for me previously for a long time.  I have not made any change to the code prior to this happening.

Below is my code for the infowindow section:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);

    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var data = markers[i]
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Permit#" + " " + data.permit,
            icon: 'GoogleMapsMarkers/' + data.icon + '.png'

        });
        (function (marker, data) {
            google.map.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                infoWindow.setContent('<b>' + data.loc + " " + data.type + '</b>' + '<br/><a target=_blank href="ViewPermit.aspx?PermNum=' + data.permit + '">' + 'Open Permit #' + " " + data.permit + '</a>');
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        })(marker, data);
    }
```

I am using the script below for the api:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;key=My_Key"></script>
```

I tried this and still same issue:

```
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=My_Key&callback=initMap">
```

Has something changed that I am not aware of?

Comment: Shouldn't `google.map.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) ...` be `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) ...` (You're missing the 's' on 'maps')

Comment: I've added the s but still getting same results.

Comment: This [simple sample JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kenejugasi/edit?html,output) is using snippet of your code and shows an infowindow with no error messages. Are you populating the `data` object correctly from the `markers[]` array?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not share any API keys, passwords, any sensible data information. Try to use placeholders e.g. (API key), [API Key].

Have you tried to follow Google's official documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows

Hope this will help you in your quest.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow!  Thanks for helping out!  It seems that your answer doesn't explicitly provide a solution to the given question, but could be very helpful advice nonetheless.  In the future, responses that do not propose a solution to the problem should probably be expressed through comments instead.  Thanks for posting!